# Sending custom variables in array from COntroller to Notifications in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to send a custom variable from the controller to Notifications in laravel 6. but Jobs jobs going to failed_jobs table in the database. I am using the following code.

Controller Code:-

```php
$notificationdetails = [
    'greeting' => 'Hi Artisan',
    'body' => 'This is my first notification ',
    'thanks' => 'Thank you for using our site',
    'actionText' => 'View My Site',
    'actionURL' => url('/')
];

$user = User::find($userid);
Notification::send($user, new LikecommentNotification($notificationdetails));
```

Notification Code

```php
private $notificationdetails;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $notificationdetails)
    {
        $this->notificationdetails = $notificationdetails;
    }
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
   return (new MailMessage)
   // ->line('The introduction to Hitesh Chauhan.')
   // ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
   // ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
   ->greeting($this->notificationdetails['greeting'])
   ->line($this->notificationdetails['body'])
   ->action($this->notificationdetails['actionText'], $this->notificationdetails['actionURL'])
   ->line($this->notificationdetails['thanks']);
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you put that extra variable in the constructor?

Comment: $notificationdetails = [
    'greeting' => 'Hi Artisan',
    'body' => 'This is my first notification ',
    'thanks' => 'Thank you for using our site',
    'actionText' => 'View My Site',
    'actionURL' => url('/')
];

Comment: The Notification's constructor. I'll writea quick answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: ok will be waiting

Comment: My bad, didn't see the __construct method before. Maybe it's failing because of a problem in the mail configuration? Have you tried setting MAIL_DRIVER=log in your `.env` to see if it fails?